# Counting the nodes in the window of size l in a lattice

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, graph, networkx

I have a networkx lattice -

```
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(5,5,periodic=True)
```

Now I want to create a window of size l where l can vary on the lattice where the centre of the window is the centre of the lattice.

All my nodes have a value attached to them. The function is -

```
 def node_status(self, node, time):
        r'''
        returns the status of a given node at a given time.

        :Arguments:

        **node**
            the node
        **time** float
            the time of interest.

        :Returns:

        **status** string ('S', 'I', or 'R')
            status of node at time.
        '''
```

Therefore I want to calculate the number of nodes which are 'R' in the window of size l. I can get the status of the nodes by calling the function on each node in the window.

For reference-

[image]

full code-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import EoN

G=nx.grid_2d_graph(5,5)
m=5

initial_infections = [print(type()) for (u,v) in G if u==int(m/2) and v==int(m/2)]

sim = EoN.basic_discrete_SIR(G,0.5,initial_infecteds = initial_infections,
               return_full_data=True, tmax = 25)

pos = {node:node for node in G}
sim.set_pos(pos)
sim.display(1, node_size = 40) #display time 6
plt.show()

def linear_distance(x1, x2, m):
    if x2>x1:
        return min(x2-x1, x1+m-x2)
    else:
        return min(x1-x2, x2+m-x1)

def in_window(node1, node2, m,L):
    D1 = linear_distance(node1[0], node2[0], m)
    D2 = linear_distance(node1[1], node2[1], m)
    max_distance = max(D1, D2)
    return max_distance <= L #True if in window

def count_nodes(G, center, m, L):
    nearby_R = [node for node in G if sim.node_status(node,1) is 'R' and in_window(node, center, m,L)]
    return len(nearby_R)

count_nodes(G,(2,2),5,3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge is likely to be to calculate if a node is within a given distance of the center, particularly since it's periodic.  So I define a function `linear_distance` which checks the distance in 1 dimension, allowing for periodicity.  Then I define a function `in_window` which uses `linear_distance` to tell whether or not a node is within a given window.  Finally I create a list comprehension that includes all nodes that are within the window and have the desired status.  You'll need to update the command `status(node)` as appropriate.

```
def linear_distance(x1, x2, m):
    if x2>x1:
        return min(x2-x1, x1+m-x2)
    else:
        return min(x1-x2, x2+m-x1)

def in_window(node1, node2, m,L):
    D1 = linear_distance(node1[0], node2[0], m)
    D2 = linear_distance(node1[1], node2[1], m)
    max_distance = max(D1, D2)
    return max_distance <= L #True if in window

def count_nodes(G, center, m, L):
    nearby_R = [node for node in G if status(node) is 'R' and in_window(node, center, m,L)]
    return len(nearby_R)
```